# R retain strings when converting vectors to character vectors to submit to API

Tags: r, graphql, data-wrangling

Ok, I suspect the answer to this question will uncover my ignorance but here it goes:

I have this `input_vector` of strings

```
input_vector <-c("string1","string2")
```

And I need to pass these items to a very complex API query which requires the `"` to be included. If I do this `stringi::stri_paste(input_vector, collapse = ',')` then the output is not usable

```
"string1,string2"
```

What I really need is

```
"string1","string2"
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
paste(shQuote(input_vector), collapse = ",")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
paste0('"', input_vector, '"', collapse = ',')
#[1] "\"string1\",\"string2\""
```

To view the actual string use `cat` :

```
cat(paste0('"', input_vector, '"', collapse = ','))
#"string1","string2"
```